# Como faço upload de arquivo php corretamente, quando tem caracteres especiais ou acentos?

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando fazer upload de um arquivo de audio no php, o problema é que o arquivo deve ser movido para um nome com acentuação, til, por exemplo.
Exemplo:
Salvo o arquivo com nome de Sebastião.mp3, mas o php na hora de mover o upload do arquivo move com o nome de SebastiÃ£o.mp3

olha o arquivo upload.php

```
$target_dir = "../../mp3/";
$nomeF="Sebastião"; <- aqui eu pego no banco de dados o nome...
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file2=utf8_encode($target_dir).$nomeF.utf8_encode(".mp3"); <- tentei codificar o arquivo mas nao deu resultado
ou
$target_file2=$target_dir.$nomeF.".mp3";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 59900000) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "mp3" ) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {

        } else {

        }
    }
```

Porém, como eu disse, o arquivo salva errado.
Alguem sabe o que fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem interessante é criar um hash usando [MD5](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.md5.php) para ser o nome do arquivo em seu diretorio e salva-lo no banco vinculando ao nome real (com acentos e caracteres especiais)

```
echo md5('apple');
//1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f
```

vejo como uma forma segura e organizada.

Comment: Então, como eu tive necessidade de resolver o problema rápido, eu peguei uma funcao que remove os acentos, e salva o arquivo sem os acentos, assim não me da problemas na hora de salvar nem de ler... Ai ficou facil, basta usar uma funcao que faça isso tanto no php, que uso pra salvar o mp3, quanto no javascript que uso pra ler o arquivo, quanto o python que tb uso pra ler o arquivo em um script : )